# Using lapply to sum a subset of a dataframe

Tags: r, sum, subset, lapply

I'm quite new to R and using lapply. I have a large dataframe and I'm attempting to use lapply to output the sum of some subsets of this dataframe.

| group_a | group_b | n_variants_a | n_variants_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | 1 | 2 |
| NA | 2 | 5 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 |

I want to look at subsets based on multiple different groups (group_a, group_b) and sum each column of n_variants.

Running this over just one group and n_variant set works:

```
sum(subset(df, (!is.na(group_a)))$n_variants_a
```

However I want to sum every n_variant column based on every grouping.  My lapply script for this outputs values of 0 for each sum.

```
summed_variants <- lapply(list_of_groups, function(g) {
              lapply(list_of_variants, function(v) {
                sum(subset(df, !(is.na(g)))$v)
```

I was wondering if I need to use paste0 to paste the list of variants in, but I couldn't get this to work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We may use `Map/mapply` for this - loop over the group names, and its corresponding 'n_variants' (assuming they are in order), extract the columns based on the names, apply the condition (`!is.na`), subset the 'n_variants' and get the `sum`

```
mapply(function(x, y) sum(df1[[y]][!is.na(df1[[x]])]), 
     names(df1)[1:2], names(df1)[3:4])
group_a group_b 
      3       4
```

---

Or another option can be done using `tidyverse`.  Loop `across` the 'n_variants' columns, get the column name (`cur_column()`) replace the substring with 'group', `get` the value, create the condition to subset the column and get the `sum`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  summarise(across(contains('variants'),
    ~ sum(.x[!is.na(get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'n_variants', 'group')))])))
```

-output

```
  n_variants_a n_variants_b
1            3            4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group_a = c(1L, NA, 1L), group_b = c(NA, 2L, 2L
), n_variants_a = c(1L, 5L, 2L), n_variants_b = c(2L, 4L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this - it's got me much closer to what I'm looking for, however I'm looking to get the sum of each variants set for each group subset. So I'd want the output to be: n_variants_a for group a=3; n_variants_b for group a=2, n_variants_a for group b= 7, n_variants_b for group_b=4. So im looking to output each n_variants for each group subset - does this make sense?